# Scanning with an Epson xp-310 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, scanner, epson

I've got an Epson xp-310 all-in-one which I'm able to print on but will not allow me scan. It says "computer not found" or simply "unavailable". My guess is that I need a scanner driver. I have tried to download one from both Epson and the Ubuntu software center (as well as a couple of other places), but can still not get the scanner to connect.

I'm thinking that I'm not installing the correct one? Or is there a problem with the Linux/Epson connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can download Epson scanner drivers from [HERE](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX)

Download deb packages according to your platform (i386 or amd64) with ltdl7 in name, place theь to your home directory and install by

```
sudo apt-get install iscan*.deb
```

You need iscan, iscan-data and a network plugin, if you need to scan over network.